# TS2307: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am just getting started with TypeScript and I am not sure why I am seeing this error in my IDE(Webstorm).

**"TS2307:Cannot find module 'express'"**

```
import express = require("express");
```

I have uninstalled/installed back the typescript globally and still see the error. I used the following tutorial as a starting point 
http://www.vandiest.biz/?p=3931

Currently, I am blocked and not sure how to proceed forward with this solution. Also I have tried recommendations on some other posts regarding the same error, but with no luck.

Comment: Have you installed the `express` npm packages and its relevant typings? `npm install express --save` and `npm install @types/express --save-dev`

Comment: The correct syntax is: `import express from 'express'` - or - `var express = require('express')`. You have the two of them combined.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The comments to your question by @Saravana and @domdambrogia are both correct.

Firstly the syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
import express from 'express';
```

Secondly you need to install the [typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573822/what-are-typings-in-typescript):

```
npm install @types/express --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

> You need to install express.js

`npm i @types/express --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

if this is failing for a nested node_module, update tsconfig.json with -

> "skipLibCheck": true