# Module not found Error: Can't resolve 'history' in @types/history

Tags: reactjs, typescript, es6-modules

Am developing a React Application where I want to use `@types/history` module..

Installed

```
npm install --save @types/history
```

And in my component file trying to import like

```
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from 'history'
```

And

```
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from '@types/history'
```

But throwing exception like

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' in
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When installing @types/history you are just providing typescript compiler with type information about `history` package. Not the package itself. See for example this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573822/what-are-typings-in-typescript) for some details.

Therefore - you must install `history` package in order to use it:

```
$ npm install --save history
```

See more info about its usage at their [github rep](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history).

Answer (score 5):

try to install history and react router dom package using npm

```
npm install --save history
npm install react-router-dom --save
```