# Integrating Express functions to Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express, single-sign-on

So my express functions worked fine in javascript but since Angular has been freaking out from dealing with .js files I'll have to convert them to `.ts`.

Basically I'm making a Service Provider to communicate a Shibboleth Identity Provider.

This code ran fine in .js but now I'm running into some errors:

```
app = express();

app.get('/metadata.xml', function(req, res) {     // What is our endpoint?
    console.log('Express.js test');
    res.type('application/xml');
    res.send((this.sp.create_metadata()));        // Create metadata for service provider
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Running login req');

    this.sp.create_login_request_url(this.idp, {}, function(err, login_url, request_id) {
        if (err != null) {
            return res.send(500);
        }
        res.redirect(login_url);
    });
});

app.post( ... ) {
...
}
```

You get the idea. When I write something like this in Angular I usually  have to use http. Right now I'm getting errors such as:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/~/node_modules/express/lib'
>       ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/~/node_modules/express/lib'

How can I get these functions to work in Typescript? Thank you!

Comment: Did you installed TS typings? `npm install --save @types/express`

Comment: @YaroslavBigus No I didn't - I will do that. Could you explain typings? I've had to use this before getting fs to work.

Comment: Here is good article how to use TS and express. https://dev.to/briandgls/using-typescript-with-express--e0k

Comment: Here is good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573822/what-are-typings-in-typescript and link to typings repository https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: Thank you. I installed the @types/express but this didn't immediately fix my issue. Any other steps I should follow? I see the express types package sitting in my package.json.

Comment: check this post https://dev.to/briandgls/using-typescript-with-express--e0k (you should import Router, and use Router.get method)